# Питон, на что можно заменить for append

Tags: python

Как в питоне заменить конструкцию такого вида

```
l1 = []
for chunk in l2:
    l1.append(chunk)
```

или

```
result = ""
for value in values:
    result += value
```

на что нибудь чисто питоновское и лаконичное?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал не использовать пустые литералы коллекций, а заменять их вызовом соответствующих функций: [] -- list, {} -- dict, () -- tuple, т.к. эти скобочки очень похожи друг на друга

Comment: @gil9red Может лучше поставить нормальный шрифт?

Comment: @Arnial, куда вы деваете энергию и байты от сэкономленных двух символов? А так, я использовал стандартный шрифт в PyCharm (не знаю какой там стоит) и временнами, обычно сонным путал скобочки :)

Comment: my_list = list(),  работает медленнее, чем my_list = []

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это:

```
l1 = []
for chunk in l2:
    l1.append(chunk)
```

Можно заменить на:

```
l1 = [chunk for chunk in l2]
```

---

Это:

```
result = ""
for value in values:
    result += value
```

Можно заменить на:

```
result = ''.join(value for value in values)
```

Главное, чтобы `value` было строкой, иначе будет ошибка вида `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`, которую нужно обойти так:

```
result = ''.join(str(value) for value in values)
```

Comment: если значения как есть копируются (как в вопросе и вашем коде), то [явные генераторы не нужны](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576650/23044).

Answer (score 2):

`l1 = list(l2)` - встроенная функция list вернет новый объект листа с копированными данными L2. Если элементы l2 неизменяемые объекты, все будет как по маслу, но если l2 содержит изменяемые элементы то это печально. Поэтому рекомендуется использовать deepcopy

```
from copy import deepcopy
l1 = deepcopy(l2)
```

можно использовать списковое включение или генератор

Cписковое включение

```
l1 = [i for i in l2]
```

вернет готовый список, то есть сперва создасться список потом вернется

Генератор

```
l1 = (i for i in l2)
```

вернет объект генератора, и при итерации l1 будет возвращат по одному объекту. в сравнении с списковым включением эконоить память

Советую прочитать разницу между ними

```
result = ' '.join(array)
```

все сработает если элементы array имеют тип СТРОКИ, но если хотя бы один элемент иного типа, то будет ошибка, поэтому лучше использовать функцию высшего порядка MAP

```
result = ''.join(map(str, array))
```

map - применить функцию к каждому элементу листа. В нашем случае каждый элемент array будет аргуентом функции str. То есть примерно выглядить так

```
str(i) for i in array
```

Answer (score 1):

- `L1 = list(L2)`
- `result = ''.join(values)`

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# конструкцию вида
l3 = []
for a in l1:
    if a > 13:
        for b in l2:
            if b > 2:
                if b == 3:
                    l3.append(a + b)
                else:
                    l3.append(a - b)

print(l3)


# можно заменить на эту, но делать так плохо
l3 = [a+b if b == 3 else a-b for a in l1 if a > 13 for b in l2 if b > 2]

print(l3)
```